# Breaking circular dependency in Python via interfaces

Tags: java, python, circular-dependency

Below code may be used for breaking circular dependencies in Java.

What is the Pythonic way of this?

```
interface A {
   int A1();
}


class X implements A {
   B b;

   public int X1() {
      b = B(this);
      b.doSomething();
   }

   public int A1() { ... }
}

class B {
   A a;
   public B(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   public doSomething() {
      //...
      this.a.A1();
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, and usually most pythonic, way to do this is to rely on duck typing, so the dependencies aren't explicit in the static code and there is no circularity.

The reason you need an interface in Java is because Java forces the `B` class to give a static type to its `a` member, and similarly for the `a` parameter to its constructor. There is no need for that in Python, because variables don't have types (values do of course, but any variable can hold a value of any type). If you want to explicitly force a check, you *can*, by using an [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)) as an interface… but it really doesn't buy you anything. Better to just let the ducks be ducks:

```
class X(object):
    def x1(self):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.b.do_something()
    def a1(self):
        # ...

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def do_something(self):
        self.a.a1()
```

Of course there's still *dynamic* circularity, but that's not a problem. (Well, the circular *references* can be a problem, but usually not, and it's not the problem you were worried about, and it's no different from Java…)